# Four Zakef-groups in one half-verse

Tags: trop-cantillation

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zakef_katan) writes:

> The most times in succession the [Zakef] group occurs is four.

It cites [*A compendious grammar of the Hebrew language* by G. F. R. Weidemann](https://play.google.com/store/books/details?id=PPNDAAAAYAAJ&rdid=book-PPNDAAAAYAAJ&rdot=1), page 48, which says:

> *Zaqef gadol* or *zaqef katon* may be continuously repeated as many as four times.

I'm fairly certain this is not an *a priori* rule but just an *a posteriori* observation. Nevertheless, where does this phenomenon occur in Tanakh? Are there any examples of five (or more) groups in one clause?

(I found yesterday that [Ruth 2:11](http://www.sefaria.org/Ruth.2.11) contains a sequence of three, and a friend found [Genesis 3:1](http://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.3.1?lang=he) as well. Still nothing with four Zakef-groups, though.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had a script run through mechon-mamre's text. There are four verses with four, and none with more than that. (Actually, two of the verses are essentially a statement and its echo.)

They are:

II Samuel 17:9
הִנֵּ֨ה עַתָּ֤ה הֽוּא־נֶחְבָּא֙ בְּאַחַ֣ת הַפְּחָתִ֔ים א֖וֹ בְּאַחַ֣ד הַמְּקוֹמֹ֑ת וְהָיָ֗ה כִּנְפֹ֤ל בָּהֶם֙ בַּתְּחִלָּ֔ה וְשָׁמַ֤ע הַשֹּׁמֵ֨עַ֙ וְאָמַ֔ר הָֽיְתָה֙ מַגֵּפָ֔ה 
בָּעָ֕ם אֲשֶׁ֖ר אַֽחֲרֵ֥י אַבְשָׁלֹֽם׃

II Kings 1:3, 1:6

וּמַלְאַ֣ךְ יְהוָ֗ה דִּבֶּר֙ אֶל־אֵֽלִיָּ֣ה הַתִּשְׁבִּ֔י ק֣וּם עֲלֵ֔ה לִקְרַ֖את מַלְאֲכֵ֣י מֶֽלֶךְ־שֹׁמְר֑וֹן וְדַבֵּ֣ר אֲלֵהֶ֔ם הֲֽמִבְּלִ֤י אֵין־אֱלֹהִים֙ בְּיִשְׂרָאֵ֔ל אַתֶּם֙ הֹֽלְכִ֔ים לִדְרֹ֕שׁ בְּבַ֥עַל זְב֖וּב אֱלֹהֵ֥י עֶקְרֽוֹן׃

וַיֹּֽאמְר֨וּ אֵלָ֜יו אִ֣ישׁ ׀ עָלָ֣ה לִקְרָאתֵ֗נוּ וַיֹּ֣אמֶר אֵלֵינוּ֮ לְכ֣וּ שׁוּבוּ֮ אֶל־הַמֶּ֣לֶךְ אֲשֶׁר־שָׁלַ֣ח אֶתְכֶם֒ וְדִבַּרְתֶּ֣ם אֵלָ֗יו כֹּ֚ה אָמַ֣ר יְהוָ֔ה הֲֽמִבְּלִ֤י אֵין־אֱלֹהִים֙ בְּיִשְׂרָאֵ֔ל אַתָּ֣ה שֹׁלֵ֔חַ לִדְרֹ֕שׁ בְּבַ֥עַל זְב֖וּב אֱלֹהֵ֣י עֶקְר֑וֹן לָ֠כֵן הַמִּטָּ֞ה אֲשֶׁר־עָלִ֥יתָ שָּׁ֛ם לֹֽא־תֵרֵ֥ד מִמֶּ֖נָּה כִּי־מ֥וֹת תָּמֽוּת׃

Ezekiel 48:10

וּ֠לְאֵ֜לֶּה תִּֽהְיֶ֣ה תְרֽוּמַת־הַקֹּדֶשׁ֮ לַכֹּֽהֲנִים֒ צָפ֜וֹנָה חֲמִשָּׁ֧ה וְעֶשְׂרִ֣ים אֶ֗לֶף וְיָ֨מָּה֙ רֹ֚חַב עֲשֶׂ֣רֶת אֲלָפִ֔ים וְקָדִ֗ימָה רֹ֚חַב עֲשֶׂ֣רֶת אֲלָפִ֔ים וְנֶ֕גְבָּה אֹ֕רֶךְ חֲמִשָּׁ֥ה וְעֶשְׂרִ֖ים אָ֑לֶף וְהָיָ֥ה מִקְדַּשׁ־יְהוָ֖ה בְּתוֹכֽוֹ׃

If your browser can't display the cantillation marks, here's a picture of the four verses:

[image: Image of four verses]

Comment: Pro tip: mechon-mamre already splits the text by verse. You then split it by etnachtas, and count zaqefs in each segment.

Comment: I feel like there should be an xkcd about this.

Comment: Care to share the script? Sounds kind of involved.

Comment: @Daniel there's an xkcd about *that*! http://xkcd.com/1513/